# Prevent duplicate record to get created

Tags: apex, rest-api

I am creating the object records which stored the pardot prospect data into custom object. Everytime I run the API it insert the record in SF and which become duplicate. So I want to put some logic like if record is already exist then it will be updated or if not exist then inserted.

I have written below logic but it is not working and not throwing any error.

```
    public List<Pardot_Prospect__c> ppobjlst {get;set;}
ppobjlst = new List<Pardot_Prospect__c>();
       Pardot_Prospect__c ppobj = new Pardot_Prospect__c();
        for (PardotProspectWrapper.prospect p : wrapper.result.prospect) {
            ppobj = new Pardot_Prospect__c();
            ppobj.Prospect_Id__c = string.valueOf(p.id);
            ppobj.Campaign_Name__c = p.campaign.name;
            ppobjlst.add(ppobj);
            }
//fetching the record to check if pardot record exist in salesforce         
List<Pardot_Prospect__c> dupProspectList = [Select Id, Prospect_Id__c,Campaign_Name__c from Pardot_Prospect__c where Prospect_Id__c = :ppobj.Prospect_Id__c];
    if(dupProspectList.size()>0){
        for (PardotProspectWrapper.prospect pp : wrapper.result.prospect) {
                dupProspectList[0].Prospect_Id__c = string.valueOf(pp.id);
                dupProspectList[0].Campaign_Name__c = pp.campaign.name;
            }
            update dupProspectList;  // updating the existing.
        }
        else
            insert ppobjlst;   // inserting if not exist  
    }
```

Can someone please guide me what's wrong in here. Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind to explain your logic a little bit, like what approach you are taking to prevent the duplicate? Beside this your SOQL does not look correct. You are adding some records in `ppobjlst` but not using this list anywhere.

Comment: Use upsert, instead of insert/update to prevent duplicates

Comment: @Frodo - I am taking the response from wrapper and string it into object List "ppobjlst" which I am inserting in the ELSE part. The same list I used to display records on the vf page.

Comment: @Santanu - I used upsert as well but that too not working incase of upsert it is inserting records but not updating the existing record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your logic. Here is the updated code:

```
public List<Id> prospectIdlist {get;set;} // Getting all prospect id in a list and querying them to check if duplicates exist.
prospectIdlist = new List<Id>();

public List<Pardot_Prospect__c> ppobjlst {get;set;}
ppobjlst = new List<Pardot_Prospect__c>();

for (PardotProspectWrapper.prospect p : wrapper.result.prospect) {
    Pardot_Prospect__c ppobj = new Pardot_Prospect__c();
    ppobj = new Pardot_Prospect__c();
    ppobj.Prospect_Id__c = string.valueOf(p.id);
    ppobj.Campaign_Name__c = p.campaign.name;
    ppobjlst.add(ppobj);
    prospectIdlist.add(string.valueOf(p.id));
}

//fetching the record to check if pardot record exist in salesforce         
List<Pardot_Prospect__c> dupProspectList = [Select Id, Prospect_Id__c,Campaign_Name__c from Pardot_Prospect__c where Prospect_Id__c in: prospectIdlist ];
if(dupProspectList.size()>0){
    for (PardotProspectWrapper.prospect pp : wrapper.result.prospect) {
        //dupProspectList[0].Prospect_Id__c = string.valueOf(pp.id); // No need to do this, as this already has same value
        dupProspectList[0].Campaign_Name__c = pp.campaign.name;
    }
    update dupProspectList;  // updating the existing.
}
else{
    insert ppobjlst;   // inserting if not exist  
}
```

Rather than doing all this, you can also simply do this(Assuming `Prospect_Id__c` is an external key field):

```
    public List<Pardot_Prospect__c> ppobjlst {get;set;}
    ppobjlst = new List<Pardot_Prospect__c>();

    for (PardotProspectWrapper.prospect p : wrapper.result.prospect) {
        Pardot_Prospect__c ppobj = new Pardot_Prospect__c();
        ppobj = new Pardot_Prospect__c();
        ppobj.Prospect_Id__c = string.valueOf(p.id);
        ppobj.Campaign_Name__c = p.campaign.name;
        ppobjlst.add(ppobj);

    }
 upsert ppobjlst Prospect_Id__c;
```

Comment: @Frodo - Second one is just like magic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

following piece of code may help you to implement the second solution.

```
projects__c newProject= new projects__c(name='Project12_update12',ExternalID__c='12');
Schema.SObjectField f = projects__c.Fields.ExternalID__c;
Database.upsert(newProject ,f, false);
```